# Mac OS X User Profile folder?

Tags: xcode, macos, global-variables, environment-variables, user-profile

Does anybody know the default environment variables in MAC OS X? What is the variable for user's folder?

For example if the path in MAC OS X is "**/Users/someuser/Applications**" Then what is the variable for the "**someuser**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like on other Unix systems, it's `$USER` and `$LOGNAME`. And `$HOME` is the path to the home directory `/Users/someuser`.